# Зачем нужен typedef?

Tags: c++, c

В чем разница между

```
typedef struct LINE
{
   ....
};
```

и

```
struct LINE
{
   ...
};
```

Comment: typedef - type declaration. Подробне читать тут http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В Вашем примере разницы нет никакой, `typedef` просто игнорируется. Если же переписать этот код немного:

```
typedef struct LINE
{

} alias;
```

То объект структуры можно будет создавать как с помощью `LINE` так и `alias`, т.к. `typedef` создаёт псевдонимы типов.

Comment: Псевдонимом в данном случае будет alias ?

Comment: @neko69, да, но Вы можете выбрать любое другое имя или даже несколько имён(через запятую)

Answer (score 12):

`typedef` используется для создания псевдонимов других типов данных.
Приведенный пример лучше скорректировать, например:

```
typedef struct LINE {
...
} t_line;
```

`typedef` может использоваться не только для структур, но и для любых других типов:

```
typedef int t_message_id;
typedef enum e_Colour {...} t_colour;
```

**Основные причины использования `typedef`-объявлений**

Сокращение имен типов данных для улучшения читабельности и простоты набора кода. В приведенном примере без использования `typedef` придется писать `struct LINE`. В C++ эта проблема решена (можно просто писать `LINE`), однако могут использоваться длинные названия типов, например: `std::vector<LINE>::size_type` может быть сокращено с помощью `typedef ... t_lvecsz`.

Абстрагирование от используемого в данной реализации типа данных для облегчения возможных изменений реализации. Например, `struct LINE` может быть объявлено так:

```
struct LINE {
    float x1,y1,x2,y2;
};
```

и во всем остальном коде для представления координат использоваться тип `float`. При возникновении необходимости перехода, например, к типу `double` потребуется вносить множество изменений в код (и, как всегда, где-то забыть внести изменения). Эта проблема хорошо решается с помощью следующих объявлений:

```
typedef float t_coord;
struct LINE {
    t_coord x1,y1,x2,y2;
};
```

Также `typedef` может использоваться для облегчения создания объявлений сложных типов (что-то вроде "массив указателей на функции, возвращающие указатель на структуру и т.д.").

Comment: Только "новые типы" лучше именовать, добавляя не `t_` в начало, а `_t` в конец. Посмотрите на все эти `time_t`, `pid_t`, `int32_t` и т.п.

Comment: @avp Суффикс `_t` зарезервирован стандартом и его лучше не применять в своих программах.

Comment: @KonstantinLes, а можно ссылку на стандарт? Не помню я такой резервации за ним

Comment: @ixSci Да, Вы правы. В стандарте резервируются только uintXXX_t и intXXX_t. Где-то я об этом читал (наверное, у Голуба). Ну и в общем-то вся логика развития стандарта это подтверждает. Здесь обсуждается эта тема: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent

Comment: @KonstantinLes, видимо это во многом зависит от того как Вы сами оцениваете свои программы. Кстати, я абсолютно не имел в виду, что в **каждый typedef** надо пихать `_t` или `t_`.