# Зачем typedef объявлять с одним и тем же типом

Tags: c, структуры, объявление, typedef

Наверно какие-то C-шные ухищрения. Навроде их классов. Вроде бы и объявление тут уже есть. Может поэтому? Вот такая строка например (из OpenCV):

```
typedef struct CvFileStorage    CvFileStorage;
```

Зачем же так писать? Не нашел никак, сходу, ответ на это. Когда-то (несколько лет назад), помню что читал об этом. Тогда чистый C был в моде наверное, а сейчас такое позабыто получается. Еще подобное видел в коде от Windows CE6 и др. Это запомнил:), а для чего нужно не помню никак. Если еще какие-то доп. куски кода надо привести, то скажите. Эта строка стоит перед структурой, которая у себя где-то в поле использует тип из этого typedef-а. Но зачем так писать, а не просто объявить его? Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужен typedef?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489890/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-typedef)

Comment: @alexolut, вроде разные вопросы?

Comment: @Qwertiy в чём? По сути всё объясняется возможность использовать тип без упоминания struct. То, что имена совпадают - всего лишь частный случай.

Comment: Наверное, более всего `typedef` востребован для объявления указателей на функции (особенно, тоже возвращающие  функции -)) / А тут это похоже на некое подражание языкам, в которых в самом деле можно объявлять свои типы.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Имеется по крайней мере две веские причины объявить этот typedef.

```
typedef struct CvFileStorage    CvFileStorage;
```

Первая причина заключается в том, что в C программах вы должны указывать ключевые слова `struct` или `enum` перед именем структуры или перечисления. Это выглядит обременительно при вводе кода. Очень часто программисты забывают указать эти слова, что приводит к появлению ошибки компиляции. Поэтому этот `typedef` упрощает жизнь программистам, позволяя им не писать эти ключевые слова перед именем структуры или перечисления.

Вторая причина состоит в том, что имена структур и другие идентификаторы находятся в различных пространствах имен. Поэтому одно и то же имя можно использовать для объявления структуры и обычной переменной. Например, следующий фрагмент кода является корректным

```
struct CvFileStorage
{
    //...
};


int CvFileStorage;
```

В этом фрагменте кода объявляется структура с именем `CvFileStorage` и переменная типа `int` с тем же самым именем. Эти объявления не конфликтует друг с другом, так как, как уже было написано, перед именем структуры обязательно должно следовать ключевое слово `struct` .

В C вы можете записать, к примеру

```
struct CvFileStorage
{
    int CvFileStorage;
} CvFileStorage;
```

Это объявление корректно, так как эти три совпадающих идентификаторs находятся в различных пространствах имен.

Однако это может вводить в заблуждение читающих код, так как если программист по ошибке опустит ключевое слово `struct` перед именем структуры, то может оказаться, что код по-прежнему с точки зрения синтаксиса языка будет корректным, хотя на самом деле имелась в виду структура, а не переменная с таким же именем.

Например, в данном выражении программист по невнимательности забыл указать ключевое слово `struct`, и тем не менее получил корректное выражение, так как имеется переменная с таким же именем

```
sizeof( CvFileStorage )
```

Чтобы избежать такой путаницы также целесообразно резервировать это имя без ключевого слова `struct`  для имени структуры, используя `typedef`..

В С++ ключевое слово `struct` можно опускать при обращении к структуре. Тогда возникает вопрос: а как быть с тем, что в C можно объявлять переменную или функцию с таким же имеенем как имя структуры?

Этот вопрос решается следующим образом: имя переменной или имя функции скрывает объявление структуры с тем же самым именем. Поэтому при обращении к структуре надо указывать уточненное имя.

Например,

```
struct CvFileStorage
{
    //...
};

void CvFileStorage();
```

В этом фрагменте кода объявление функции скрывает объявление одноименной структуры.  Поэтому если, например, вы хотите объявить объект этой структуры, то надо будет указывать уточненное имя структуры.

```
struct CvFileStorage obj;
```

Или, например, можно написать такие объявления

```
struct CvFileStorage
{
    //...
};

void CvFileStorage( struct CvFileStorage );
```

Эти имена не будут конфликтовать друг с другом, так как для структуры используется ее уточненное имя.

Comment: Блин... Божественно! Вот это объяснение все-таки. (!) У них (OpenCV) и есть как раз структура (как предикат получается) и функция с одинаковыми именами (см. ниже). И на них я "застрял" в задумках сильных. Вот они (очень возможно есть еще и другие, но про них я не знаю покаест):

Comment: Что-то не могу добавить код по этому поводу - структура такая 
struct RoiPredicate
{
    RoiPredicate( const Rect& _r ) : r(_r)
    {}

    bool operator()( const KeyPoint& keyPt ) const
    {
        return !r.contains( keyPt.pt );
    }

    Rect r;
};
(из features2d/src/feature2d.cpp) и есть также функция с таким же именем RoiPredicate. Теперь есть над чем еще подумать еще раз. Спасибо.

Answer (score 13):

В с++ если нужно объявить переменную типа структуры, нужно просто написать имя типа и переменную. В чистом си это не так. И нужно всегда писать struct. Это все потому, что типы для структур и остальные типы как бы находятся в разных областях видимости. Но так как программисты существа ленивые, то лучше один наз написать

```
typedef struct CvFileStorage    CvFileStorage;
```

и потом не задумываться, почему оно не компилируется (потому что забыли struct) или почему оно работает как то странно (потому что забыли struct, а кто то объявил свой тип не структуру с таким же именем).

Но часто пишут ещё интереснее:

```
typedef struct {

// тут объявление структры
} struct_name;
```

В этом случае создается сразу все так, как привычно в обычном с++.

Comment: А Вам, если честно, как минимум, 10-ти кратное спасибо, если такое возможно. Т.к. теперь еще стал думать с позиции C vs C++ при разборке ихнего хедера (это из core//types_c.h) не зря же еще там есть директивы проверки #if cplusplus (или как точно будет ее синтаксис - неважно тут). Я просто пишу код с использованием части от ихнего и натолкнулся на этот typedef. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: многие с удивлением узнают, что с и с++ хоть и очень похожи, а на самом деле два разных языка. И если нужно обеспечить два языка одновременно, то иногда нужно следить очень внимательно (классика - значение `sizeof('a')`). А 10-кратное - это просто галочка возле голосов "за" :)

Answer (score 12):

Без этого `typedef` при любом упоминании структуры `CvFileStorage` надо писать полностью:

```
struct CvFileStorage  cv;
void func(struct CvFileStorage* cv);
```

и так далее. При наличии объявления `typedef` слово `struct` можно выбрасывать:

```
CvFileStorage  cv;
void func(CvFileStorage* cv);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @AleksBak "спасибы" тут ценятся в форме таких зелененьких галочек... :)

Comment: Какие "зелененькие галочки"? Стрелки вижу снизу/сверху цифр вижу, но они серые и послу нажатия на верхнюю она стала оранжевой. Это наверное флуд уже будет и правила форума мне стоит почитать, но почему и тут не спросить и не всегда есть время на все.

Comment: Нашел вроде :) Они серые изначально - эти "зелененькие галочки". И отметил там где надо (человек несколько раз редактировал свой ответ, написал позже т.к. намного/намного подробнее написал ...)