# Работа typedef c++

Tags: c++, типы

Хотелось бы немного разобраться с работой `typedef`. В определении написано, что оно является синонимом для типа, который мы указали. И у меня возникает вопрос: как это -  синоним? Ну тоесть объявление `typedef int my_int` будет в некоторой степени эквивалентно `#define my_int int`, только у typedef-объявлений своя область видимости. И при компиляции `my_int` будет заменяться на `int`? Каким образом это работает?

Comment: Нужно определение "синонима типа" в C++ или в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Вообще, можно бы и [задубликатить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489915/176217)

Comment: пометил, очень очень похоже на дубликат

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, определение синонима типа

Comment: Немного пробежался по стандарту. Каких-то особых определений для слова «синоним» (_synonym_) не нашёл. Видимо данное слово используется в общечеловеческом смысле. Т.е. получается, что задаваемая через `typedef` последовательность символов, идентификатор обозначает в точности ту сущность, для которой уже имеется некоторый другой идентификатор. Просто синтаксический сахар, чтобы вместо скучного `int` можно было писать `my_SuPeR_mega_intEGER_type`.

Comment: @wololo надо уже упразднить `typedef` в пользу `using`, но слишком много легаси не даёт. Да и в стандарте всё это называется как *"typedef-name"*

Comment: @wololo, извините, я просто глупый, но мне не понятен принцип работы `typedef`, оно работает как макрос, или добавляет еще одно имя к описанию типа?

Comment: `добавляет еще одно имя к описанию типа` Напишите подробнее, что вы здесь имеете ввиду?

Comment: ok, ладно. Это работает примерно так. Написав `typedef int my_int`, вы говорите компилятору, что идентификатор `my_int` обозначает тип `int`. Везде где компилятор встретит идентификатор `my_int` (с учётом областей видимости конечно же) он должен считать, что там написано `int`. Чем-то похоже на пару `&&` и `and`. Они обозначают одно и тоже. `and` альтернативный способ написать `&&`. `typedef` позволяет задавать альтернативные способы написания для уже имеющихся сущностей. Синтаксический сахар.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую описать типичные сценарии

Самое простое - это писать короткие названия типов, типа

```
    typedef unsigned long long ulong;
```

и теперь вместо длинного названия типа переменной `unsigned long long` можно писать просто ulong

Второе упрощение (пришедшее прмо из C) - работа со структурами, что то вроде

```
struct args {
    char* name;
    int age;
};
```

В С пришлось бы при определении каждой переменной писать `struct args arg1;`.

Но можно написать

```
typedef struct args_t {
    char* name;
    int age;
} args;
```

и тогда определения переменных будут такими: `args arg1;`

И - да, при компиляции короткие названия будут заменяться на полные.